# How many prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ contain $10$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

This is an exam question I don't think I got. It asked how many prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ contain $10$.

I know the prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are principal ideals generated by primes, and the prime ideals are either $(1+i)$, $(p)$ when $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ for $p$ an integer, and if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then $p=(a+bi)(a-bi)$ for conjugate primes $a+bi,a-bi$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

I think $(1+i)$ is a prime ideal containing $10$ since $10=(1+i)\cdot(1-i)\cdot 5$. Any prime ideal containing $10$ must also contain at least one of $2$ or $5$, and I don't think there are any primes congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ which are divisible by $2$ or $5$.

I then thought of elements of form $a\pm bi$ where $a^2+b^2=p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$ which could possibly divide $10$. I thought of $1\pm 2i$ and $2\pm i$, as they all divide $5$. Including $(1+i)$, does this mean there are three prime ideals containing $10$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$10$ has the prime factorization $10 = -i(1+i)^2(2+i)(2-i)$. Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD, these are the only primes that divide $10$. Hence there are only the three prime ideals you found.